# why does this code seem to die prematurely?

Tags: php

I have two files - test.php and demo.php.

The contents of test.php:

```
<?php
// fails if allow_url_include = 0 (which it generally is by default)
if (!defined('INIT_NAMESPACES')) {
    define('INIT_NAMESPACES', true);
    $str = substr_replace(file_get_contents(__FILE__), ' namespace phpseclib;', 5, 0);
    include('data://text/plain;base64,' . base64_encode($str));
    return;
}

class test {
    function zz() { echo 'aaa'; }
}

echo "THIS FAR";
?>
```

The content of demo.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('test.php');

echo "ALL DONE";
?>
```

Running demo.php yields THIS FAR being output but not ALL DONE. Any ideas as to why?

As for what I'm trying to do...  although I don't think it's that relevant this is a test script to test the feasibility of code that uses namespaces but can also work without them on PHP4. But let's not let that distract us from the question. The question I'm asking isn't about namespaces or PHP4 or anything like that - it's about why ALL DONE isn't being displayed.

Thanks..

Comment: Start echoing more things or commenting out lines to see what happens.

Comment: Is the if block being evaluated? The return statement in it is probably ineffective, btw.

Comment: why do you have `return` in your code?

Comment: @Ibu That's legal; see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: I agree with @Xeoncross. Comment everything out except the echoes (and the `include` in demo.php, of course) and see if it works, then uncomment little by little and see when it stops working.

Comment: @ken that's not the point. Return will halt the execution and the class will never get defined.

Comment: @Ibu: never forget how evil PHP can be. What's happening here is that, when `INIT_NAMESPACES` is not defined, it will define it, run a modified form of the current file (injecting `namespace phpseclib;` at position 5), and then exit (using `return`). In the modified form, the code path with `return` is never taken. It's comparable with `#ifdef INIT_NAMESPACES\nnamespace phpseclib;\n#endif` in a C preprocessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `test.php` replace `$str = ...` line with :

```
$handle = fopen(__FILE__, 'r');
$str = fread($handle, filesize(__FILE__));
fclose($handle);
$str = substr_replace($str, ' namespace phpseclib;', 5, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the code worked. I was being a complete moron and calling test.php and not demo.php lol :O